# SQL one to one without relation

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

Using Oracle 11
I'm wanting to pull data from a table, and add a column of calculated values which come from a subquery statement.

Example Table1 is:

```
COLUMN1:   COLUMN2:
1          Group1
3          Group2
5          Group3
6          Group4
```

The subquery returns different values each time the query is run, but for the sake of this example let's say it returns thes values:

```
2
4
7
8
```

What I need is to combine the results

```
COLUMN1:   COLUMN2:    COLUMN3: (subquery - order does NOT matter)
1          Group1      2
3          Group2      4
5          Group3      7
6          Group4      8
```

But because the subquery is being calculated with each row return from the table, all I am getting is.

```
COLUMN1:   COLUMN2:    COLUMN3: 
1          Group1      2
3          Group2      2
5          Group3      2
6          Group4      2
```

There is no way that I can think of to relate the table and the subquery, I've tried playing with ROWNUM but with no luck.

**UPDATE**

```
SELECT GD.*, N
  FROM patrongroupsdesc GD,
       (SELECT n
          FROM patrongroupsdesc GD2,
               (SELECT n, ROWNUM
                  FROM (    SELECT ROWNUM n
                              FROM DUAL
                        CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 100)
                 WHERE n >= 1) SUB
         WHERE SUB.n = GD2.groupid(+) AND GD2.groupid IS NULL) SUB2
```

table PATRONGROUPSDESC is formatted as follows

```
groupid (NUMBER)
description (VARCHAR2)
...other data
```

SUB returns the values 1-100
SUB2 returns the gaps in groupid numbers
I'm essentially duplicating all data in this table except for one column

Comment: Can you include the SQL you've tried thus far?

Comment: Show your SQL we might be able to help then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you must know that if you don't have an `ORDER BY` clause then the order of the results comes with **no guarantee at all**.

Then, you can do:

```
WITH first_table AS (select *, ROWNUM AS rn FROM ...)
   , secnd_table AS (select *, ROWNUM AS rn FROM ...)
SELECT first_table.*, secnd_table.*
  FROM first_table INNER JOIN secnd_table USING (rn)
```

The trick here is that `ROWNUM` is assigned as a result comes out from a `SELECT` statement. Therefore if you want to paste tables like this, you must SELECT from your tables and store rownum in another column, and then from those two subselects you can join.